# VBA Code to make a string variable bold and underline

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have this working code but would like to apply bold and underline to this line of code:

```
.InsertBefore "Please Review, loan not financeable for bond in its current state." & vbCr & vbCr & boldtext & vbCr & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("C32").value _
```

​I tried using a variable called boldtext and am using the /b to bold but it displays the email as if it were regular text with the /b as if it wer part of the string.

How can I tweak this to make the text bold and underline?

```
Public Sub ScreenShotResults4_with_Current()
Sheets("Manager Report").Unprotect Password:="Mortgage1"
        Dim Rng As Range
        Dim olApp As Object
        Dim Email As Object
        Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
        Dim boldtext As String
        boldtext = "<b>Issue:</b>"
       Call HideAllImages

        Set Rng = Sheets("Manager Report").Range("C4:F35")
            Rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        'Sheets("Summary").Branch_ChkBox.Visible = False
        
        'Row1Circle Sheets("Summary").CheckBoxes("Branch_ChkBox").Visible = False
        
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With
    
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
  '            Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor
    
        'strbody = "See production data for most recent 3 months.  "
    
        With Email
            .To = Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F2").value
            .CC = Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F3").value & ";" & 
 "kirk.hudson@lgimortgagesolutions.com" & ";" & "carrie.budds@lgimortgagesolutions.com" & ";" 
  & 
  "Courtney Barreto" & ";" & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("D5").value
            If Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F24").value = "Not Financeable" Then
            .Subject = "Manager Report " & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("D6").value & " 
  " & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("D4").value & _
            " (" & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F5").value & " )" & " NOT FINANCEABLE"
            End If
            If Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F24").value = "Additional Docs Needed to 
  Proceed" Then
            .Subject = "Manager Report " & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("D6").value & " 
  " & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("D4").value & _
            " (" & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F5").value & " )" & " MAYBE"
            End If
            If Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F24").value = "Submitted to Processing" 
 Then
            .Subject = "Manager Report " & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("D6").value & " 
 " & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("D4").value & _
            " (" & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F5").value & " )" & " GOOD-TO-GO"
            End If
            
            
'            End If
            '.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Calibri>" & "</p>" & 
  strbody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature
            .Display
                    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor
            wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
        
            'if need setup inlineshapes hight & width
   With wdDoc.Content
    '--- paste the range image first, because it overwrites
    '    everything in the document
    
    .PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    .InlineShapes(1).Height = 750
    
    '--- now add our greeting at the start of the email
  '        .InsertBefore "See current year production data and current pipeline. " & vbCr & 
   vbCr
    If Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F24").value = "Not Financeable" Or 
   Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("F24").value = "Additional Docs Needed to Proceed" Then
    .InsertBefore "Please Review, loan not financeable for bond in its current state." & vbCr 
    & vbCr & boldtext & vbCr & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("C32").value _
    & vbCr & vbCr & "Solution:" & vbCr & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("C38").value & 
    vbCr & vbCr ' & vbCr & .Font.Bold & "<u><b>Issue: </u></b>"
    Else
    .InsertBefore "Please Review, loan looks good, submitted for processing. " & vbCr & vbCr
    End If
    '--- finally add our sign off after the image
    .InsertAfter vbCr & vbCr & _
                 "Thank you" & vbCr & vbCr
                 
     End With

    
            .Display
        End With
    
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    
        Set Email = Nothing
        Set olApp = Nothing

'Sheets("Summary").Range("K17").Visible = True
'Sheets("Summary").Protect Password:="Mortgage1"
 Call ShowAllImages
 End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder available in Word to find properties and methods required for getting the job done? When you don't know which property or method to use you may turn on the macro recorder and do the required steps manually in Word, so you will end up with a code generated where you can find all the required staff.

Comment: I actually did but it shows me the code to make a selection bold and underline but I don't have a selection, I have text in my vba code that I want to bold and underline

Answer (score 0):

`InsertBefore`  returns a `Range` object, you can make it bold:

```
set boldRange = .InsertBefore "Please Review, loan not financeable for bond in its current state." & vbCr & vbCr & boldtext & vbCr & Worksheets("Manager Report").Range("C32").value 
With wdDoc.Range(Start:=boldRange.Start, End:=wdDoc.Content.Start - 1)
    .Bold = True
End With
```

Comment: I tried adding this multiple ways and cannot get the placement and syntax correct. I only need the work "Issues:" bolded and underlined. Can you help me with the proper syntax using my original code?